# How to find the unique objects from an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array object like

```
var array = 

[
    {"name":"Joe", "age":17},
    {"name":"Carl", "age": 35},
    {"name":"Joe", "age":17},
    {"name":"Carl", "age":35},
    {"name":"Mark", "age":21},
]
```

Whats the best way to fetch the unique objects from this array without doing loopings, in this case output need to be

```
[
    {"name":"Joe", "age":17},
    {"name":"Carl", "age": 35},
    {"name":"Mark", "age":21}
]
```

Comment: "without doing loopings". There is no way,

Comment: you might be able to express it in terms of higher-order functions instead of an explicit loop, but the looping will occur anyway.

Comment: You tagged the question with underscore.js so did you actually look at their documentation or google for your answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
new Array(...new Map(a.map(d=> [d.name, {name: d.name, age: d.age}]))).map(d=> d[1]);
```

1. a.map(d=> [d.name, {name: d.name, age: d.age}]: return array contain
   [name, {name:abc, age:10}]
2. new Map(a.map(d=> [d.name, {name: d.name, age: d.age}])) save unique
   value
3. new Array(...new Map(a.map(d=> [d.name, {name: d.name, age:
   d.age}]))): convert map to array
4. new Array(...new Map(a.map(d=> [d.name, {name: d.name, age:
   d.age}]))).map(d=> d[1]): from array only take secon elemnt means 
   {name: d.name, age: d.age} only

Answer (score 2):

Try the lodash library and uniq method:  This might work with underscore too.

https://lodash.com/docs#uniq

```
_.uniq([{ 'x': 1 }, { 'x': 2 }, { 'x': 1 }], 'x');
// → [{ 'x': 1 }, { 'x': 2 }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com) its very easy.

```js
var array = 
[
    {"name":"Joe", "age":17},
    {"name":"Carl", "age": 35},
    {"name":"Joe", "age":17},
    {"name":"Carl", "age":35},
    {"name":"Mark", "age":21},
];
  

  var result = jinqJs().from(array).distinct('name', 'age').select();
  document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + '</pre><br><br>';
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fordth/jinqJs/master/jinqjs.js"></script>
```